# to retrieve a mysql data in php and echo the retrieved data

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
    <?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "xxxxxx";
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);    
     $query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'";
    mysql_select_db('xxxxxx', $link);
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($link));
     $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
     mysql_close();

  $rows = array();

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $rows = array();
  while($r = mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {
   $rows[] = $r[0];
   }
   print_r($rows); 
   ?>
```

This is my code i want to display the roll number of the currently logged in user and 
when i run this code i get no database selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should code properly, means database connection and database selection should be on top:

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "xxxx";
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db('xxxx', $link);

    $query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($link));
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $rows = array();
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $r[0];
    }

    print_r($rows);
    mysql_close();
   ?>
```

Also moved `mysql_close();` on last
One other main point was, now `mysql_` is deprecated, please use `mysqli_`

Answer (score 1):

Remove this statement from line number 10

```
 mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have closed the connection from MySQL before the `mysql_query` `mysql_close();`
try this

```
    <?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "dfsdftwsdgdfgdfsgsdf";
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);    
     $query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'";
    mysql_select_db('xxxxxxx', $link);
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($link));
     $num = mysql_num_rows($result);


  $rows = array();

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $rows = array();
  while($r = mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {
   $rows[] = $r[0];
   }
  mysql_close();
   print_r($rows); 
   ?>
```

---

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

just remove these two lines before while that will solve ur problem

```
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $rows = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and use mysql_close function in the last.

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "xxxxxx";
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);    
     $query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'";
    mysql_select_db($database, $link);
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($link));
     $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

  $rows = array();

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $rows = array();
  while($r = mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {
   $rows[] = $r[0];
   }
   print_r($rows); 
   mysql_close();
   ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The order should be like this

```
 mysql_select_db('meipolytechnic', $link); 


$query = "SELECT rollno FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'";
    mysql_select_db('meipolytechnic', $link);
```